# Where to build hunters in Settlers II?

Tags: the-settlers-2

What are good spots to build hunters in the Settlers II? Since my settlement inevitably expands, hunters eventually end up in the middle of it and their productivity goes towards zero. In fact, even if they're near a forest at the outskirts of my settlement, I rarely see a hunter with decent productivity. What are the requirements for a productive hunter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, hunters will never give you a large and steady supply of food. That's why a hunter's hut is a small building while a bakery or a butcher require a system of multiple large and medium buildings to operate. Hunters are most useful at the beginning, while your farms aren't set up yet.

(Fisherman huts are also small buildings and they do produce a steady amount of food, while they're still operating, but they run out of fish after a while and, unlike game, fish never come back.)

That being said wildlife population can differ from map to map so if you don't see any wildlife running around, don't bother building a hunter. If there is wildlife, you'll have the most chance of success near a forest and you should make sure not to cut the forest down while your empire expands.

You can still run out of game, but if you wait a while, it might come back as long as the forest is still there.

Comment: So basically a hunter is a rather temporary thing that becomes mostly obsolete with farms?

Comment: @deceze: Yes, pretty much. There's no harm in keeping a bit of forest alive for the hunter to hunt, but once you got your farms, butchers, and bakers running, you're not dependent on the hunter being productive anymore.